# SQL Specific time AND Specific Date Range

Tags: sql, oracle

How do I say in my SQL call for a specific time (from 0500 hrs - 0600 hrs) on the date range of 07/01/2013 - 09/30/2013?

I am wanting to use the MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART field.  This example shows everything from 07/01 - 09/30.  I just need the ones from 0500hrs - 0600hrs on the same date range.

Thank you!

```
FROM MOPUSER.MOPACTIVITY
WHERE TO_CHAR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') BETWEEN '2013-07-01 00:00:01' AND '2013-09-30 23:59:59'
```

Comment: is this a time stamp or an oracle date?

Answer (score 2):

Do two comparisons, one for date and one for time:

```
FROM MOPUSER.MOPACTIVITY
WHERE TO_CHAR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART, 'yyyy-mm-dd') BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2013-09-30' and
      TO_CHAR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART, 'hh24:mi') BETWEEN '05:00' AND '05:59'
```

You can also simplify the second condition, using `hour()`:

```
FROM MOPUSER.MOPACTIVITY
WHERE TO_CHAR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART, 'yyyy-mm-dd') BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2013-09-30' and
      hour(MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART) = 5
```

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in `hour()` function in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

How I did it.  I like @Gordon Linoff's answer better!

```
SELECT MOPACTIVITY.MOPID ,
TO_CHAR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') AS MOPSTART_DATE,
TO_CHAR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPEND, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') AS MOPEND_DATE,
MOPACTIVITY.MOPCREATOR,
MOPACTIVITY.MOPIMPLEMENTOR
FROM MOPUSER.MOPACTIVITY
WHERE TO_CHAR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART, 'yyyy-mm-dd') BETWEEN '2013-07-01' AND '2013-09-30'
AND to_number(to_char(MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART, 'sssss')) between 18000 and 21600

Order by MOPACTIVITY.MOPID
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach that might leverage an index (if there is one) on `MOPSTART` would be something like this:

```
WHERE
    MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART >= DATE '2013-07-01'
    AND
    MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART < DATE '2013-09-30' + 1
    AND
    TO_CHAR(MOPACTIVITY.MOPSTART, 'HH24') = '05'
```

This assumes that you *don't* want to include 06:00.